# HTML5 number field not working for decimals without leading zero on Android 4

Tags: android, html, mobile, input, decimal

I have this input field:

```
<input type='number' />
```

When entering **.5** on an Android 4 device, the number disappears after the field loses its focus.

**Tested on:**

- Samsung Galaxy S2 - Android 4.0.3
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2 - Android 4.0.4
- Samsung Galaxy S3 - Android 4.1

Is this a known Android browser bug and has anybody figured out a workaround?

Comment: Did you set a maxlength attribute to your input?

Comment: No, should I? I'm using the same html for the field as mentioned above.

Comment: No but I noticed that when I set a maxlength attribute to my input (for numbers only) when I reached the limit, I lost the focus as you described.

Comment: Oh ok, the field is not losing the focus itself while typing, the field loses its focus after you tap outside of the field (which is expected) but the number disappears (which is not expected).

Comment: May you could try to insert a pattern to your input text. Try this and see if it works : `<input type="number" name="name"
           pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?"/>`

Comment: Thanks, I tried different patterns before. I tried your example and also this example `<input type="number" name="name" pattern="[0-9]*([\.|,][0-9]+)?"/>` ([0-9]* instead of [0-9]+ before decimal point) now again but same issue.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea about how to solve that =(.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help though! Maybe others can either confirm this issue or have a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

We worked around the problem with this little snippet of javascript:

```
var keycodes = {
    period:190, decimal:110
};

$('input[type=number]').keyup(function (e) {
    if (!this.value && (e.keyCode === 190 || e.keyCode === 110)) {
        this.value = '0.';
    }
});
```

It checks to make sure the textbox has no value (a single decimal left the value of the textbox either null or an empty string on my test devices), then adds a leading zero to the textbox.

I suspect this method may have issues, but I haven't seen any yet.